# Assigning template to CA - no templates node under my CA

Tags: windows-server-2012, certificate-authority

I am trying to follow steps to create a cert for ADFS. The steps I'm looking at are [on the microsoft website](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn781428.aspx). The steps are somethign like this:

1. Create a new template by duplicating WebServer
2. Assign the new template to a CA
3. Request a certificate using the template

I get up to the "Assign a template to the CA", but I get stuck there because I don't have a "templates" node under my CA. My view looks somethign like this:

[image]

But according to the instructions, I should have a "Certificate Templates" node.

So that's where I'm stuck. Incidentally, if I try to request a new certificate, it tells me no certificates are available. I can override that and see my certificate disabled because it can only be issued to a computer. I'm not sure if that's an issue...

My details:

- Server set up from scratch as 2012 R2 Standard domain controller into a new forest, no computers joined yet.
- I set my operational level to 2012. I am
  working on the DC (and I added the DC with the permissions, as
  mentioned in the instructions)
- I am logged in as a Domain Admin /
  Enterprise admin user.
- The CA is set up as a stand-alone, root CA, on the DC. No other CAs.

Could someone point out what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most likely installed your Certificate Authority in *Standalone* instead of *Enterprise* mode which doesn't support using AD integrated templates.

More information in this Technet article:
[Stand-Alone Certification Authorities](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755290.aspx)